Java project panama - cannot convert MethodHandle(VarHandle,MemorySegment,long,double)void to (VarHandle,MemorySegment,int)void
I have this issue on java 22 where I am trying to set Point2D as struct and set two points x, y, but I am getting WrongMethodTypeException. The code is working on JDK21, but not on JDK22.
My error is
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.invoke.WrongMethodTypeException: cannot convert MethodHandle(VarHandle,MemorySegment,long,double)void to (VarHandle,MemorySegment,int)void
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.asTypeUncached(MethodHandle.java:903)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.asType(MethodHandle.java:870)
    at StructKt.main(Struct.kt:20)
    at StructKt.main(Struct.kt)

var POINT_2D: MemoryLayout = MemoryLayout.structLayout(
    JAVA_DOUBLE.withName("x"),
    JAVA_DOUBLE.withName("y")
)

val handle_x: VarHandle = POINT_2D.varHandle(PathElement.groupElement("x"))
val handle_y: VarHandle = POINT_2D.varHandle(PathElement.groupElement("y"))

// This doesn't work in java 22
fun main() {
    Arena.ofConfined().use { arena ->
        val point = arena.allocate(POINT_2D)
        handle_x.set(point, 11)
        handle_y.set(point, 22)

        handle_x.get(point).also { println(it) }
        handle_y.get(point).also { println(it) }

    }
}



Try passing doubles instead of integers, ie 1.0, 2.0

You should set the base to 0. Try handle_x.set(point, 0, 11)

I'd be mildly surprised if you could make VarHandles and MethodHandles work correctly from Kotlin at all, which you appear to be using.
